# Summing Multi-Dimension Arrays - Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sum a multi-dimensional array in VBA.

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T55Fb.png)

My goal is to have the sum of MyArray(2,2) = 121, and of MyArray(3,1) = 129, all of this stored in "MyNewArray".

I tried using Application.Worksheetfunction.Sum but I guess this wouldn't work unless I printed my values to Excel.

Any ideas of how I could go about it?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all of this stored in MyNewArray"?

Comment: If you look at the picture I posted, I am adding a new Array called “MyNewArray” to store the sum. It is not necessary to be there if it all can be stored in “MyArray”

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the elements of the vector that interests you and sum up the values one by one. It looks cumbersome but it's very fast.

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim Arr     As Variant
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim Sum     As Double
    
    ReDim Arr(1 To 5, 1 To 2, 1 To 9)
    Arr(2, 2, 2) = 1
    Arr(2, 2, 3) = 120
    Arr(3, 1, 4) = 1
    Arr(3, 1, 6) = 59
    Arr(3, 1, 7) = 69
    
    For i = LBound(Arr, 3) To UBound(Arr, 3)
        Sum = Sum + Arr(3, 1, i)
    Next i
    MsgBox "Total = " & Sum
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like this works if I wasn't interested in storing the sum to a new array. I guess that I could've made myself more clear, but I wanted to have the sum stored on a new Array (e.g. Sum(3,1) = 129).

Comment: I tried changing your code to "Sum(j,z) = Sum(j,z) + Arr(j,z,i)" after having j and z as new variable on the For loop but I get "Object variable or With block variable not set" error

Comment: That error occurs when you try to access an object that hasn't been created - something to do with your changes, not with my code. I would guess you forgot to set the variable `Arr`. But apart from that, are you sure it's even possible to tell all the layers of your multi-vector arrays apart? Consider using Types or Collections or a Dictionary - anything that enables you to call your numbers by their names.